# api.ai - Not resolving correctly my address

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm using api.ai to build a chatbot for my city (Toulouse, France) and to know when the garbage collection service is according to your address.
It works fine for every case except one : 
When I type :

> Quand passent les poubelles au 38 allées Jean Jaurès Toulouse ?

The resolved value for my parameter $address is just "Jean Jaurès" (it should be *38 allées Jean Jaurès Toulouse*)

[image]

If I change "allées" to "rue" or "avenue", it works and I have the full address. But with "allées", no.
[image]

Something weird is that in the training panel, the resolved value shown is good. 
[image]

Do you have any idea how I can fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Did you save the changes you made in training (can you see the changes in the intent now)? 2. Have you saved your agent and allowed the agent's training to finish before trying the query again?  3. Have you set your API.AI agent's language to French?

Comment: Yes I did all you mentioned. But last week, I talked to a Google Expert and he told me that french address was not 100% supported (even if the agent is configured in French).